# Function to make a trajectory more straight

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, sql, trajectory

I'm new at PostGIS and I have to do a project for my university course.
I'm trying to analyze a trajectory of points that I downloaded from my runtastic app but it's a mess. 
There are some points where the trajectory goes back and forth (green line in the image), while my real trajectory was straight (pink).

[image]

Is there a query or function I can use to delete those points and make my trajectory a bit more straight?

Comment: It's not an easy problem as it would be hard to tell the difference between a random loop, as in your image, and a genuine sharp turn at a junction. You could probably write a rule to do this by comparing the angles between consecutive linestrings and removing those that exceed some tolerance, but, it's a non-trivial problem.